# Non wood basement panels

Tags: basement-refinishing

What are options for non wood basement panels. I would prefer ones that could be taken down to get behind the panels if needed. I'm looking to the install myself.

Comment: When you say *non-wood*, do you mean to exclude wood derived products, such as MDF and hardboard? Also, what is the purpose? Just decoration? Screening of utilities? Protection of something? Rigid barriers to entry?

Comment: I'm looking for a rigid product along the walls. I do not want any wood or wood type product in the event it gets wet.

Answer (score 2):

There are many types of "basement paneling systems" on the market that do what you want.  I have personally used [Owens Corning](http://basements.owenscorning.com/bfs/index.aspx) which is top of the line.  I thought it was pretty good.

Some general advice:

- I have renovated 50+ basements and have gone the paneling route twice.  It really should be a last resort.  Basically you should fix the water problem if you want things in the basement.
- using paneling, cost about 3-4 times the amount I would spend on drywall and lumber.
- the paneling isn't the easiest thing in the world to install.  Maybe it is because my team wasn't used to it but we are much faster going through the traditional method.
- no matter what anyone tells you the paneling will not look as good.  At best it looks like a well done industrial office space.  At worst it looks like you are on a bad movie set.
- the benefit of being able to take out the panels easier is pretty cool.  On one basement we did it wasn't even about the outside water it was that the house had plumbing along all the walls in the basement (don't ask me copper must have been free back then - and changing this would have meant redoing pretty much the entire house)